# Android toasting Listview element?

Tags: android, listview

I am creating a listView in Android using the following code :

```
 ListView listView = (ListView) List.this.findViewById(R.id.mylist);
         listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

         String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" ,"asdsad","asdsdsa","asdasdsa"};

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,R.layout.list_item,values);

            // Assign adapter to ListView

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setVisibility(0);
```

**Now I want to Toast a selected Item from my ListView so I use the following code :**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {

                    String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
```

But Unfortunately I am getting error for the following piece of code

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id)
```

The error is

**The type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method 
     AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick(AdapterView, View, int, long)**

So What Should I do to correct this error and also print my listview element?
**Edited**
**Entire Code**

```
package com.notification;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.*;

public class List1 extends Activity 
{

Context context=this;

@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);
        //ListView
        try{

         ListView listView = (ListView) List1.this.findViewById(R.id.mylist);
         listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

         String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" ,"asdsad","asdsdsa","asdasdsa"};

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,R.layout.list_item,values);

            // Assign adapter to ListView

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setVisibility(0);

            //required
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id)
                //public void onItemClick(ListView<?> listview, View view, int position,long id)
                {

                 Toast.makeText(List1.this, "hi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });


            //required
            }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
       }
}
```

Nothing is getting toasted. why?

**Edit 2**
**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/textview1"
    style="@style/textview_text"
    android:textSize="16dp">


</Button>
```

**listview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I got the solution. Actually I needed to add this statement import android.view.*. It was a silly mistake from me.

Comment: why..button as as list item..for try use..`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` instead `R.layout.list_item` in your ArrayAdapter.

Comment: @Frankenstein Its working but Y its not working with list_item?

Comment: @Frankenstein I got it! I shouldnt have used button there. One more silly mistake. Anyways thanks a lot 2 u!

Comment: yes..it didnt let item get click..if button is there..it goes for button click..in that case you might need to go for custom array adapter..to get click of button..

Comment: @Frankenstein Yea thats right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set your **java compiler version to 1.5** so its giving error.

Two things you can do.

1) remove `@Override` written before *onItemClick*

2) `right-click project - properties - java compiler - check-Enable project setting - change to 1.6`

Also there is other changes required.

Use `YouActivityName.this` instead `getBaseContext()` while showing `Toast`

Item can be null so change...`String item = values[position]`

Comment: Now its not showing any error.But in emulator When I click a item,Its not doing any action. I actually toasted "Hi" inside onclicklistener but nothing s being displayed. :(

Comment: I tried this :  Toast.makeText(List.this, "hi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();. List is my activity name still nothing is happening :(

Comment: I changed it to List1.java but still same prob

Comment: I tried this : String item = values[position];
                 Toast.makeText(List1.this, item,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); Still same :(

Comment: Instead of ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,R.layout.list_item,values); , If i use  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);. Its working

Answer (score 2):

Change the Style of List Item to R.layout.simple_liast_item_1 rather than a custom one.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
```

Comment: But what if I want to use custom one. Why does the setOnItemclick not working with custom one?

Comment: place a TextView in layout and create adapter as : ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row,R.id.textView1,values);

Comment: Thanks alot. now its working. The error was in my list_item.xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    final String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
       "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
       "Linux", "OS/2" ,"asdsad","asdsdsa","asdasdsa"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

       // Assign adapter to ListView

       listView.setAdapter(adapter);
       listView.setVisibility(0);

       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                   long id) {

               String item = values[position];

               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           }
       });
```

Comment: @Krishkant Dalal I am getting this error : The type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method 
 AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long)

Comment: @Kishkant Dalal Yea I tried but the same error was shown in eclipse

Comment: I got the solution. Actually I needed to add this statement import android.view.*. It was a silly mistake from me. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I am getting this error : The type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long)